# Mac OS X, how to compile a .c file for ARM and disassemble it after?

Tags: c, arm, disassembly

I want to disassemble a simple .c file:

```
#define UPPER 15 
const int lower = 12;
int sum = 0;

int main(void) { 
  int i;
  for(i = lower; i < UPPER; i++) 
  { 
    sum += i;
  }
return sum;
}
```

To get the assemblercode for ARM CPUs on my Mac Mini 10.8.3. There fore i am stuck at:

- How do i create the ARM executable for the above .c file?
- How to disassemble the executable after that?

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: 1. Use an ARM cross-compiler suite. For example the one included with the iPhone SDK, the Android NDK or Sourcery CodeBench.  2. Use `objdump` with the `-d` or `-D` switch (should be included with the aforementioned cross-compiler suite).

Comment: You can do this entirely in Xcode  i) create an iOS application in XCode. ii) Open source code iii) Select 'Assistant editor view' iii) Click 'Counterparts' in the bread-crumbs above the counterpart view, then select 'Assembly' off the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To compile** (assuming the target is iOS 6.0):

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos c++ -arch armv7 -marm -march=armv7-a -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -g -O3 <any other options ...>
```

**To disassemble:**

```
otool -tdv <your binary>
```